# Vertical lines connecting blocks in Gedit

Tags: gedit, indentation

I'd like to know if there is some way I can get `gedit` to display vertical lines connecting logical blocks of a programming code (namely Fortran 95 in my case).

[image: ss#1]

See in the image above, for an example. Note how in the middle and rightmost windows the blocks of `if` and `endif`, `program` and `end program`, etc., have a vertical line connecting them?  Visually this would help me a lot.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add this feature to `gedit`?

Comment: Those are called _"indent guides"_. Unfortunately, gEdit doesn't support this feature. If you absolutely need it  you have three options: 1. request this feature on [gedit mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gedit-list) (don't hold your breath though); 2. write a [gedit plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo) (if you know `python`); 3. switch to another editor, more feature rich.